# Celery: dynamically allocate concurrency based on worker memory

Tags: celery

My celery use case: spin up a cluster of celery workers and send many tasks to that cluster, and then terminate the cluster when all of the tasks have completed (usually ~2 hrs).

I currently have it setup to use the default concurrency, which is not optimal for my use case. I see it is possible to specify a `--concurrency` [argument in celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#concurrency), which specifies the number of tasks that a worker will run in parallel. This is also not ideal for my use case, because, for example:

- cluster A might have very memory intensive tasks and `--concurrency=1` makes sense, but
- cluster B might be memory light, and `--concurrency=50` would optimize my workers.

Because I use these clusters very often for very different types of tasks, I don't want to have to manually profile the task beforehand and manually set the concurrency each time.

My desired behaviour is have memory thresholds. So for example, I can set in a config file:

```
min_worker_memory = .6
max_worker_memory = .8
```

Meaning that the worker will increment `concurrency` by 1 until the worker crosses over the threshold of using more than 80% memory. Then, it will decrement concurrency by 1. It will keep that concurrency for the lifetime of the cluster unless the worker memory falls below 60%, at which point it will increment concurrency by 1 again.

Are there any existing celery settings that I can leverage to do this, or will I have to implement this logic on my own? [max memory per child](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#max-memory-per-child-setting) seems somewhat close to what I want, but this ends in killed processes which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Celery does not provide an [Autoscaler](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/internals/reference/celery.worker.autoscale.html) that scales up/down depending on the memory usage. However, being a well-designed piece of software, it gives you an interface that you may implement up to however you like. I am sure with the help of the psutil package you can easily create your own autoscaler. [Documentation reference](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/workers.html?highlight=autoscale#autoscaling).

Comment: I did further research based on what you linked, and found a gist on github that does almost exactly what I want: 
https://gist.github.com/speedplane/224eb551c51a74068011f4d776237513